# A co-worker is copying my personal projects

Tags: colleagues, projects

A co-worker is copying a project of mine I developed on my free time and walked him through (as education) so that he can learn the basics of SEO and can do similar stuff.

I've heard from another worker that he made a nearly exact clone of the website but he claims to have done the programming on it's own. The destructive point is, that the ad revenues on my website are plummeting because his site begins to rank similar on searches.

I sat down and analysed both websites and can say the sites are identical only the one is red and the other one is blue. The clone websites uses my research and techniques, data and tools. So it's nowhere near impossible to do something like this without the prior knowledge and the tools required to do so.

This is so rude and I'm very angry, how can I make my point clear the best way?

Comment: `The clone website uses my research and techniques, data and tools.` <- What tools exactly? Are they project files that are stolen from you? Compiled executables? If any intellectual property is stolen, you can warn him in an appropriate way and if he continues, get a lawyer and send a cease-and-desist to his website.

Comment: Well tools equals code necessary to gather information to supply the website with data. Tools that I've written. The problem is, I shared the code with a goodwill and not to be used to profit from it.

Comment: OK, the code taken is your intellectual property, you can bring this to a court and demand payment or cease of operations. I guess there is also a chance that the data source may change, rendering the code useless and solving the problem by itself.

Comment: Well yes both I simply want to confront the co-worker about this misbehaviour. Changing variable names does not make it your own code.

Comment: OK so you have access to undisclosed information. First you need him to disclose that information. If he does, you can tell him that he is reducing your profits with the code he took from you and warn him appropriately. If he doesn't, you can still say that you can take legal action and let the legal experts decide whether it is your code or not. In any case it is your right to protect your own intellectual property.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the workplace; the fact that the other person is a co-worker appears to have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Well it happened IN the workplace.

Comment: @HerrK ok I added it for the record

Comment: If you taught him SEO as part of your work, he learned it as part of his work, which means he shouldn't be using it for his own profit. Tell the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so you have access to undisclosed information. First you need him to disclose that information.

If he does, you can tell him that he is reducing your profits with the code he took from you and warn him appropriately.

If he doesn't, you can still say that you can take legal action and let the legal experts decide whether it is your code or not.

In any case it is your right to protect your own intellectual property.